# How to exclude password from user object sent in response in express.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am returning a response object with the user and jwt token whenever a user logs in. But I want to exclude the password field when the user is sent in the response.

**Controller:**

```
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Check for user email
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
    res.json({
      user: user,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
  }
});
```

if I exclude the password when finding the user like this:

```
const user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
```

Then bcrypt's compare method will not work as it needs `user.password`.

Please tell me how I can exclude password from user object in JSON response?

Answer (score 4):

You can set undefined to the user password before returning the user.

```
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // Check for user email
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
    user.password = undefined;
    res.json({
      user: user,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
  }
});
```

Or you can use the toJSON method in the user schema to exclude password:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: {
      transform(doc, ret) {
        delete ret.password;
      },
    },
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you send the object, set the field to `undefined` and it will exclude the property from the object:

```js
// Setting password to undefined before sending it
user.password = undefined;

return res.status(200).send({
  success: true,
  message: "Logged in successfully",
  user: user,
});
```

Output:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Logged in successfully",
    "user": {
        "_id": "6553d713648c28a777453dff",
        "name": "Name",
        "email": "name@gmail.com",
        "role": "user",
        "createdAt": "2023-11-14T20:22:43.046Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-11-14T20:22:43.046Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go on with your solution (const user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");) . just put it inside the if statement . before convert the response to json
(user = user.select('-password')).

```
if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
  user= user.select('-password');
  res.json({
   user,
   token: generateToken(user._id),
  });
 } else {
    res.status(400);
   throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).